# How to load large text with custom font in View Pager android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, textview, android-pageradapter

I am developing a small application. In this Application I am trying to load ArrayList of String and Images Url in View Pager.So that User can swipe and see images and Text.

But problem is that if user try to check last page the Mobile hangs and shows the **ANR** that this app would like to close.I am doing like following:

```
myviewPager.setAdapter(new ImprovedAdapter(NewsDetail.this, allItems,false));
myviewPager.setCurrentItem(itemposition);
```

I tried to shorten the text. View Pager does well.But I need to show the whole text and image. Is there any better way to do this or Is there any way to lazy load text in text view.

Comment: Paste ImprovedAdapter and NewsDetails code please to see what can be enhanced to speed things up.